# Is it possible to get the delivery status of a specific message in ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I want to be able to know the status of all messages that I sent. Is that possible in ActiveMQ? If so, how can I get a sent message by its ID and check whether it was received or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can subscribe to the Advisory Messages and configure the broker to emit and advisory when a message is consumed: http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

See the section about configuring the destination policy for advisoryForConsumed="true"

`<destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
       <policyEntries> 
           <policyEntry topic=">" advisoryForConsumed="true"/>
           <policyEntry queue=">" advisoryForConsumed="true"/>
       </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>`